# Why are my Commands Only Working for 1 Person

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I’m not sure what happened, I can’t seem to find anything in the code that would cause this, but suddenly only one person can use commands. Even commands set for certain permissions can’t be used by anyone except that person. The person it got stuck to is fairly new to the server too which is strange. It seems to work fine on our testing server but on the main one it’s only working for 1 person.

Below is my main file where I have the command handler

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');
const profanities = require('profanities/index.json');

var used = false;

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot Online!');
});

// This is the start of the main function when the bot is turned on
client.on('message', message => {

    if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;

    const words = message.content.toLowerCase();
    if (words.includes('shalomi')) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          message.channel.send(`Shut up ${message.author}`);
        }, 1500);
    }

    if (words.includes(' bum ')) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          message.channel.send('Are we talking about <@458068171241553921>?!');
        }, 1500);
    }

    if (words == 'prefix') {
        message.channel.send(`The current prefix is "${prefix}".`);
    }

    if (used) return;
    else {
        if (words == 'f') {
            message.channel.send('F');
            used = true;
            setTimeout(() => {
                used = false;
            }, 1000 * 20);
        }
    }

    for (let x = 0; x < profanities.length; x++) {
        if (message.member.roles.some(role => role.id === '483641589193900043')) return; 

        else {
            if (message.content.toUpperCase().includes(profanities[x].toUpperCase())) {
                message.channel.send('Oooooooh you said a bad word!');
                client.channels.get('484375912389935126').send(`Message was deleted due to use of a blocked word:\n\n"${message.content}"`);
                message.delete();
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    // The bot will not respond if there is no prefix,
    // the user that typed it was a bot,
    // or if it was not sent from in the server
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;

    // Creates the arguments variable and separates it with a space
    // and creates the command variable
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName);

    if (command.guildOnly && message.channel.type !== 'text') {
        return message.reply('I can\'t execute that command inside DMs!');
    }

    try {
        command.execute(message, args);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.channel.send('There was an error trying to execute that command!\nCheck the console for details.');
    }
});
// This logs in the bot with the specified token found in config
client.login(token);
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: “Please let me know what you need to look at”

Comment: I'd say show all your code (hide the token though)

Comment: I have edited the original post with the entire main file's code

Comment: Try moving 


`
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;

    // Creates the arguments variable and separates it with a space
    // and creates the command variable
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;
`



All the way to the top, right under `if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, couldn't format the code properly in comments. Try putting

```
 if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;

    // Creates the arguments variable and separates it with a space
    // and creates the command variable
    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (!client.commands.has(commandName)) return;
```

All the way at the top, right after the `if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;` line.

Comment: moving the code didn't do anything unfortunately. The commands were working fine when those lines were added in. I'm thinking it might have something to do with the random bits of code towards the top of the main function. I added those in last. Could a variable there or some of the if statements be affecting who uses the commands?

Comment: Hmm.. I don't see anything wrong with the code though. Maybe try removing the first if statement (`if (message.author.bot || !message.guild) return;`) and running the code without it. What happens?

Comment: Same thing nothing happens. I do have a concern though that may have been the root cause of this issue but I want to see what you think about it. I'll post the code as an answer

Comment: Alright, sounds good. Also, I was just thinking that perhaps you might want to use a switch statement for the commands.

Comment: I honestly am new to discordjs so I followed a website guide that used the methods I have in the codes I have posted.

Comment: Switch statements are actually really basic and I think you can get a hang of them pretty quickly. Here are some resources you can use: 
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch)
(https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

It'll just make your code cleaner.

Comment: Ok I'll take a look. But in the meantime any ideas on my other post regarding the new command I added?

Answer (score 0):

So here is the most recent command I did which was done a couple days ago. When I first did this command, I forgot to put the comma and semi colon at the bottom (the ones that are there now) like I was supposed to. When I tested it in the normal server, the first person to use the command is now the only person that can use every command.

Would forgetting those punctuations be the reason why every command now only works for that person who used the "hug" command first? I've tried deleting that command and redoing it thinking it would delete information that could possibly be saved to a variable. Like maybe it's looking for that one author only since it never closed out of the loop? I'm not sure

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'hug',
    description: 'Used to hug everyone or mention a user to hug them specifically.',
    execute(message, args) {

        args = message.mentions.users.size;

        if (!args) {
            message.delete();
            return message.channel.send(`${message.author} gives a big ol' hug to everyone!`);
        }
        else {
            message.delete();
            return message.channel.send(`${message.author} sends love to ${message.mentions.users.first()} with a hug!`);
        }
    },
};
```

Comment: If you missed the commas at the top (name, description) it should be an error in the code editor. I don't think it'll change who goes first though

Comment: The thing is there was no error in the editor and the code still worked. I don’t think it’s determining who goes first I think maybe because I missed the endings that it didn’t just return out and start fresh and instead maybe saved the user that happened to be the first one to use that command. Idk it’s just a theory. Doesn’t help that I’m not getting more opinions with the negative vote

Comment: Yeah, the code doesn't seem to have any problems. Not too sure why. You could, as I said before, use switch, but that probably isn't the issue.

Comment: Yeah thanks anyway. I wish someone else could step in and take a look. If I can’t get commands working I don’t know what I’m going to do

Comment: Yeah, no problem. I think that if everything fails, you may want to copy all the files into a new file and create a new bot application in the portal. Then just use the new file (with the code you saved) and try it again.

Comment: So I just kind of tried what you said. I have a second application for the bot that I test the code out on which stays in another server. The commands work perfectly fine in the testing server. I just invited the bot to the real server and same thing no commands work suddenly. They still work perfectly fine in the testing server but for some reason there's an issue with the normal server and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm thinking there's perhaps something with the roles or something that's causing this. Might want to check that out. (Check server settings and channel settings too)

Comment: I figured out the issue. I narrowed everything everything down and found out the profanity filter caused the problem. I commented it out and the commands work again. I’m assuming the check I added caused some issues so I’m going to take a look at it and get that working again. Thank you for your help though

Comment: Ah I see. Yeah, no problem, glad you figured it out!